# Finding a stronger version of Cayley-Bacharach Theorem that applies in the case that the intersection multiplicities are not equal to $1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, elliptic-curves

**Cayley–Bacharach theorem**: Assume that two cubics $C_1$ and $C_2$ in the projective plane $\mathbb{P}^2$ meet in nine (different) points. Then every cubic that passes through any eight of the points also passes through the ninth point.

> **Question** (can be found in Gathmann's 2002 Algebraic Geometry notes): Can you find a stronger version of this statement (Cayley-Bacharach Theorem) that applies in the case that the intersection multiplicities in $C_1 \cap C_2$ are not equal to $1$?

I proved Cayley-Bacharach theorem by two different ways and this is an exercise that I found in Gathmann's notes of Algebraic Geometry. He suggests to find a stronger statement for this theorem.

Since this is interesting and could be used to prove the associativity of the addition law on elliptic curves, I research it and the best that I got is the following:

**Cubic Cayley-Bacharach Theorem**: Let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be cubic curves in $\mathbb{P}^2$ without common components and assume that $C_1$ is smooth. Suppose that $C_3$ is another cubic curve that contains $8$ of the intersection points of $C_1 \cap C_2$ counting multiplicities. Then $C_3$ pass through the ninth point of $C_1 \cap C_2$.

(Found in page 21 of http://goo.gl/QjzQpm )

On wikipedia I found: Every cubic curve $C$ on an algebraically closed field that passes through a given set of eight points $P_1,\ldots,P_8$ also passes through a certain (fixed) ninth point $P_9$, counting multiplicities.

What do you think that is the stronger version that we are supposed to find?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please look up Max Noether's theorem, often referred to as $AF+BG$ theorem.

Comment: David Eisenbud, Mark Green and Joe Harris: [_Cayley-Bacharach theorems and conjectures_](https://www.msri.org/~de/papers/pdfs/1996-001.pdf), Bulletin American Math. Society **33** (1996) 295-324.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland Can you please write your comment in answer form to give you the bounty? Nice paper!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David Eisenbud, Mark Green and Joe Harris: [*Cayley-Bacharach theorems and conjectures*](https://www.msri.org/~de/papers/pdfs/1996-001.pdf), Bulletin American Math. Society **33** (1996) 295-324.